# IndexOf match result positive on unknown character

Tags: c#, .net

My IndexOf result is producing a positive result when I'm expecting it to be -1

My string I am searching in is something like

```
string source = "|BLAH|BLAH|RESULTS|BLAH|BLAH|";
```

and my search string is

```
string toFind = "|RESULTS�|";
```

It contains some unknown character that is not supposed to be there but is.  And I'm expecting this line to return -1

```
int indexFound = source.IndexOf(toFind, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This is returning the index of the string |RESULTS|.
Anyone know why? Or how to overcome this?  I want an exact match.

Comment: Please read the REMARKS section of [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says ignorable characters or ignored when doing culture sensitive comparisons.

Try this

```
int indexFound = source.IndexOf(toFind, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: this worked thanks, I didn't know about the ignorable characters